# MKAnnotation "title" property, how to suppress when using left/rightCalloutAccessoryView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

The situation in iOS 5 appears to be that a callout will not be displayed for a MKAnnotationView when the id's title is nil. MKAnnotationView Class Reference:

> (If the annotation’s title method returns an empty string, the
>   annotation view is treated as if its enabled property is set to NO.)

What I want to do is display a callout entirely composed of views, no NSStrings. There will be a string on my leftCalloutAccessoryView but moving it to title is going to mess up the design. For one thing it is not in the system font but must match the rest of the app.

Can a MKAnnotationView be made to pop up a callout composed entirely of the views returned by leftCalloutAccessoryView and rightCalloutAccessoryView, with no title between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
annotation.title=@" ";
```

don't set the `title` string to empty, set one space character in string, in this way the no string will be shown in title and your callout will be displayed properly.

Comment: It leaves empty space at the top.